# Need to know where to correctly place the finish() function to close an activity

Tags: android, activity-finish

I am stuck trying to figure out where exactly to put the finish() function in my code.

I have tried putting it on line 43 of ProfileActivity or lines 39 or 56 of MainActivity.  I'm very new at this and have read what the purpose of finish() is but can't figure out where else in my code it should go.

These are just nippets of the code ... there is more (all the Activity lifecycle functions), but I omitted to save space.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

SharedPreferences sp;
EditText email;
public static final String ACTIVITY_NAME = "PROFILE_ACTIVITY";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.thisEmailIsPassedToPage2);
    sp = getSharedPreferences("Lab3", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String savedString = sp.getString("Email", "0");

    email.setText(savedString);
    Log.e(ACTIVITY_NAME, "In Function onCreate() in MainActivity:");

    Button login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, 
            ProfileActivity.class);
            EditText et = 
                (EditText)findViewById(R.id.thisEmailIsPassedToPage2);
            intent.putExtra("typed", et.getText().toString());
            startActivityForResult(intent, 2);

        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
data) {

    int i = 0;
    i++;
    //if request code is 2, then we are coming back from ProfileActivity
    if(requestCode == 2){
        EditText et = 
(EditText)findViewById(R.id.thisEmailIsPassedToPage2);
        String fromProfile = data.getStringExtra("typed");
        et.setText(fromProfile);
        Log.i("Back", "Message");
    }
}

public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SharedPreferences sp;
private ImageButton mImageButton;
public static final String ACTIVITY_NAME = "PROFILE_ACTIVITY";
public static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profileactivity);
    Log.e(ACTIVITY_NAME, "In Function onCreate() in ProfileActivity:");

    Intent fromPrevious = getIntent();
    String previousTyped = fromPrevious.getStringExtra("typed");


    EditText enterText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    enterText.setText(previousTyped);

    mImageButton = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    mImageButton.setOnClickListener(bt -> {
           dispatchTakePictureIntent();
    });
}

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent(){
    Intent takePictureIntent = new 
Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
     }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        mImageButton.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}



These are the screenshots:  
[MainActivity1stPage][1]
[ProfileActivity2ndPage][2]
[AfterImageButtonPressed][3]
[AfterTakingPictureAndPressingOK][4]
```

Comment: You shortened your code to save space and you referred to lines by number. We have no clue where you're thinking of putting your call to `finish()`.

Comment: My apologies .... added mentioned line #s

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting it right, your flow is `MainActivity` starts `ProfileActivity` for result, then in `ProfileActivity` you start the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`for result, so I'm guessing that with that result you want to trigger your `MainActivity onActivityResult`. So if that the case you need to `setResult and finish` at the `onActivityResult`of your `ProfileActivity`.

Comment: The flow is to 1)enter an email and password and press Login. 2)It sends you to the ProfileActivity page with the email and has a button to take a picture.  3)You click on the ImageButton to take a picture and 4)the picture should replace the button.  I have been messing with my code all day ... had the picture thing working at one point (should have stopped while i was ahead). The point I am at now is when I take the picture and click ok (which is a check mark) I get a message saying "Unfortunately, Lab3 has stopped".

Comment: The button which is replaced with the image is the one in the `MainActivity`?

Comment: Its really quite large.  But only 1 null pointer exception.  I didn't get that before so I must have changed something inadvertently.    PS:  The ImageButton that should be replaced after taking the picture is on the second page. I can add a screenshot if that's allowed?

Comment: Ok, so first of all I think you don't need to start for result the `ProfileActivity` so you just can start it and finish the `MainActivity`. Yes you can add screenshots.
Also I see this `mImageButton.setOnClickListener(bt -> {
           dispatchTakePictureIntent();
           setResult(2);
           finish();
    });` you are finishing your activity and setting the result, so the `onActivityResult` from `        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);` will never get called and it may be causing you NPE.

Comment: I removed the setResult(2); finish(); from the code.  I had added it thinking that's where it should go (taken from your original comment - but not knowing where to put it).  I still get an NPE on this line in the MainActivity ... "String fromProfile = data.getStringExtra("typed");".

Comment: Do you have this in github?